# AWS CFT Glue add sampling in DynamoDB Target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, sampling, glue-crawler

I have so far Glue Crawler defined in Cloud Formation Template as:

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
Properties:
  Name: CrawlerName
  DatabaseName: DBName
  Targets:
    DynamoDBTargets:
      - Path: DynamoDBTableName
```

How I can turn on `enable sampling` option available in UI Console, but I do not see it in AWS Documentation of CFT

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but this might work based on how the aws api for glue is structured

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
Properties:
  Name: CrawlerName
  DatabaseName: DBName
  Targets:
    DynamoDBTargets:
      - Path: DynamoDBTableName
      - ScanAll: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the default is to enable sampling you shouldn't have to add anything to the CFN template. I did try "ScanAll: True" to try and disable sampling but the command doesn't seem to be supported.

Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/Targets/DynamoDBTargets/1}: [ScanAll]]